# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Hi guys I have the following problem :

I have a back-end server written in Spring and working with `PostgreSQL`. At first, all was OK but now my friend created a SQL script for filling the database with test data. And here we go :

```
19:46:30,253 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_pkey"
19:46:30,254 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)   Detail: Key (id)=(1) already exists.
19:46:30,254 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2497)
19:46:30,254 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2233)
19:46:30,254 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310)
19:46:30,254 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446)
19:46:30,254 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370)
19:46:30,255 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:149)
19:46:30,255 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:124)
19:46:30,255 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
19:46:30,256 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    ... 158 more
```

In that script, we also have some test data for users. And this error is throwing during an attempt to sign up. I understand, this error saying that I cant save user with an existing id to the database. But I actually did not set the id for the user. When I send user to `save()` method user `id = null`, and I believe that Hibernate should look at the database or at `user_id_sequence` and choose last `id + 1` for the current saving user. At least it worked like that until we filled our database with the test data. The question is why Hibernate is not choosing (last id + 1) but trying to save a new user with an existing `id = 0`? Is there any way to solve it?

Id generating strategy :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = {"deleted", "updated"})
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // ...
}
```

Hibernate configuration :

```
datasource.url=**********
datasource.username=**********
datasource.password=**********
datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.batch.size=200
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Sql script looks like a simple script for filling the database with test data :

```
INSERT INTO public.country (id, created, deleted, updated, code, name, telephone_prefix, continent_id) VALUES (101, NULL, false, NULL, 'ISR', 'Israel', 972, NULL);
....
```

Comment: Do you have a sequence defined for the table's primary key? If so: you may want to set the generation type to `SEQUENCE`. See [this baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers) for details.

Comment: @Turing85 I tried to set the strategy to GenerationType.SEQUENCE, and also with SequenceGenerator create a sequence. But it didn't help and I get: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Comment: Please add the schema of your table to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you specify a an ID for your seeded data script ? If you do and they are positive numbers, you can try changing the ID to negative numbers. If you don't specify the ID you can try specifying the ID and make them negative numbers